# Using fingerprint reader from lenevo thinpad T460p

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I am trying to use the fingerprint reader from my Lenovo T460p laptop.
Doing lsusb I get:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b541 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0090 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 12d1:15c1 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I assume the fingerprint reader is the Validity Sensors, but I have no Idea.

Googling I only found things for older thinkpads/fingerpint readers.

**Edit**
the command fprint-entroll gives this output:

```
list_devices failed: No devices available
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding to [this (old) answer](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Validity-Fingerprint-Reader-Linux/m-p/3372137/highlight/true#M7991) from the lenovo staff, there is no Linux support for the fingerprint sensor.

> Synaptics does not have any linux driver for the new touch-style fingerprint sensor in P50/P70/T460s/etc. There is nothing for Lenovo to release or support.

Anyways there is [a bugticket](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94536#c19) that could give you some hope.

> I've been in touch with people that has contacts with Synaptics internals and basically they said that they can't disclose the protocol for this generation of devices. While they try to improve the thing for future devices, they're, at least, working to make a binary driver available. No ETA known, though.

Answer (score 3):

For the Validity Sensors `138a:0090` fingerprint scanner in my T460p I got it to work using the [forked version of fprint with vfs0090 support](https://github.com/3v1n0/libfprint/blob/vfs0090/README.md).

Just follow the instructions from that page and open up the users settings to enroll a fingerprint for login.